# Why is there no solution set for $|x-7|<-4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am asked to find the solution set fot $|x-7|<-4$.

I arrived at $(-\infty, 3)\cup(11, \infty)$

For $x - 7 > 0$:

$x-7<-4$

=> $x<3$

For $x-7 < 0$:

$-(x-7)<-4$

=> $-x+7<-4$

=> $-x<-11$

=> $x>11$

So, I arrive at a solution set of:

$(-\infty, 3)\cup(11, \infty)$

However, my textbook says "no solution". Why is there no solution?

Comment: The magnitude of $x-7$ is always $\ge0$

Comment: You wrote: "for $x-7>0:\ x<3$" and "for $x-7<0:\ x>11$", but then you forgot about the conditions $x-7>0$ and $x-7<0$. Can it be that $x-7>0$ AND $x<3$ at the same time? Can it be that $x-7<0$ AND $x>11$ at the same time?

Comment: Bacuase *absolute value* is a number $\ge 0$.

Comment: Take any of your alleged solutions, e.g. $x=12$, and substitute it into the original inequality. Does it satisfy $|x-7|<-4$? Then repeat this check for each step in your argument until you find the error.

Comment: It is not true that $x - 7 < -4 \color{red}{=} x < 3$.  You should say that $x - 7 < -4 \iff x < 3$.

Comment: There is a solution set which is **the empty set**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the absolute value is on the "less than" side, the conjunction is "and", not "or."  You've discovered that $x<3$ AND $x>11$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

If you graph the solution on a x-y plane you get...[image: this plane]
As you can see if you graph all of these according to y, $|x-7|$ can never reach -4, hence, no solution. :))

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value, or the **magnitude**, of a number or an expression will always be non-negative ( $ \geq 0 $). That is why $ |x-7| < -4 $ has no solution.

Comment: This sounds very intuitive now that you put it like that, thanks for the tip